# Compare data in two spreadsheets and output the data to third spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets, the first just has 1 column with `user_id` in it.
The second has `customer_id` (which is the same as `user_id` from the first sheet) and `status`.

How can I find all the rows that match the id from the first spreadsheet in the second spreadsheet and output the status for that row into a third spreadsheet?

Example data:

Spreadsheet 1:

- user_id
- 1111
- 2222
- 3333
- 4444
- 5555

Spreadsheet 2:

First column

- customer_id
- 1111
- 2222
- 3333
- 4444
- 5555

Second column

- status
- active
- pending-payment
- active
- cancelled
- active

I'm not entirely sure but I think it's something like this:

`=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

It's pulling through a status but not what is expected.

Comment: Please provide information on the attempts you've made so far to solve that problem. It would seem like VBA is the easiest way to go here.

Comment: or you could dig super user for answers, some suggested using [spreadsheet compare](https://superuser.com/a/820086/534347). but never tried myself..

Comment: @M.Schalk I think the formula at the bottom of the question is along the right kind of lines???

Comment: If you already have the ID's and their status in the second sheet, why do you want to replicate that in a third sheet? Wouldn't your outcome be the same as your second sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, this can be done with an `Index/Match` statement like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),2)
```

Where you change your sheets and ranges to the correct ones. This will match the first entry from sheet 2 (customer ID) to range A:A (user ID) in sheet 1, then return the value from sheet 1 column B (status) when there is a match. You can put this in sheet 3 and drag the fill handle down to cover all of sheet 2.

However if I read the question right there might be an option that multiple matches are possible. If so, this is better done with an vba loop. Let me know if you want me to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before, if you want it done though VBA, where it will loop down the rows till the defined last row comparing some columns against one another and copy pasting the row into a new sheet. You can definitely work from the code below by changing a few things.

```
Sub finddata()

Dim s As Worksheet
Dim uniqueId As String
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim finalcolumn As Long
Dim offset As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

uniqueId = Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("G100000").End(xlUp).Row
finalcolumn = Sheets("Data").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
offset = 3

Set s = Sheets("Data")
Set rngSearch = s.Range(s.Cells(2, 5), s.Cells(finalrow, 5))

Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1:C100000").ClearContents

    For i = 2 To finalrow
        uniqueId = s.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=uniqueId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If rngFound Is Nothing Then
            s.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
            Sheets("DataValidation").Range("A1048575").End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
    Next i

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Or, you can use a nice if(index(match, but this won't give you a result to copy paste it into a new sheet, it will give you a good way to filter for matched values though

Answer (score -1):

You can compare like this as shown in the below screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6K3U.png)

You will get your result as shown in the second screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhK0Y.png)

Comment: That's not what the question is asking.